# Linear gradient not appearing in firefox even though correct prefix is used

Tags: html, css

Recently I have been coding a clicker game, and have found the need to use a meter to display progress. I wanted the meter to have a gradient that goes from light pink to cyan, and it works perfectly on chrome. However, when I used my home computer and booted up firefox; the gradient was no longer displayed; and the meter was a dull shade of green.

```
.pastrymeter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
    background : linear-gradient(90deg, lightpink, cyan);
}
```

This is the styling for the meter; and nothing that I have changed fixes it. I tried adding the moz prefix to the background tag; which did nothing. I also tried changing background to background-image to see if it was an element thing; but that also did nothing.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is cross-browser compatible.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, lightpink, cyan);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#cfddac), to(#fff));
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cfddac', endColorstr='#ffffff');
background: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(207,221,172),rgb(255,255,255));
```

Change the values as you may require

Can you try this second method ?

```
<div style="background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FE1C4A 22%, #AB244A 61%);
         background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #FE1C4A 22%, #AB244A 61%);
         width: 200px; height: 100px; text-align: center;">
    </div>
```

Comment: I have added a second method, can you try that?

Comment: One important thing to note is that the element is a meter rather than a div. Did not work; tried switching to a meter and even including meter inside the div but neither worked. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are targeting a non-standard feauture `-webkit-meter-optimum-value`, that isn't supported in Firefox.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-meter-optimum-value

Comment: Ah, that's irritating. Thanks!